# Searching complex JSON data for matching key value

Tags: javascript, json, loops, nested-loops

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem. I've searched and found a few answers to similar questions, but the JSON data in all the examples was too simple. Mine is more complex.

I have an array of numbers which I am looping through. For each loop, I need to match the number against my JSON data to find matching entries and then get specific key values from that entry.

This is an example of my array:

`results = [377, 375, 373, 353, 355]`

This is an example of my JSON data:

```
{
    "count": 10,
    "posts": [
        {
            "title": "Title of Post",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 377,
                    "images": {
                        "full": {
                            "url": "http://example.com/images/foo.jpg",
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 600
                        },
                        "thumbnail": {
                            "url": "http://example.com/images/foo_thumb.jpg",
                            "width": 150,
                            "height": 150
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 355,
                    "images": {
                        "full": {
                            "url": "http://example.com/images/bar.jpg",
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 600
                        },
                        "thumbnail": {
                            "url": "http://example.com/images/bar_thumb.jpg",
                            "width": 150,
                            "height": 150
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        // 9 more posts...
    ]
}
```

For each number in `results`, I need to match it against each `posts.attachments.id`. So, in this case `377` and `355` are matches. For all matched attachments, I need to grab its `full` and `thumbnail` URLs.

Like I said, I've found possible solutions for this, but the example data is only 1-2 levels deep. I can't quite wrap my head around the loops necessary for this particular scenario.

Comment: IF your question has been answered, please accept one of the answers and up vote them to not let unanswered question float around. And also rewarding people for answering your question, without there would be less incentive to do so.

Comment: Steady on. Please give people at least 24 hours to do things like eat, sleep, and other non-coding activities. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var urls = [];
results.forEach(function(result){
    posts.forEach(function(post){
        post.attachments.every(function(attachment){
            if(result === attachment.id) {
                urls.push({
                    id: attachment.id,
                    full: attachment.images.full.url,
                    thumbnail: attachment.images.thumbnail.url
                });
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

A lot of nested foreach loops here, which you should always keep to a minimum,
but it all boils down to how big your data is and will be in the future.

the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a native javascript function and imo makes it way more readable then traditional for loops. The [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method lets you break the loop by returning false so you don't have to traverse the whole list unless matching on the last element in the array.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I like the use of the EC5 methods as they are easier to read and are inline with my project's browser support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var urls = [];
var att = posts.attachments;
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var id = results[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < att.length; j++) {
        if (att[j].id == id) {
            urls.push({
                id: id,
                full: att[j].images.full.url,
                thumbnail: att[j].images.thumbnail.url
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Faster typer than me >: +1

Comment: You upvoted so quickly, it seemed like it was before I even submitted it. :)